# Missing Network shares in wx.FileDialog

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wxpython, samba, filepicker

I'm using Xubuntu 8.10 with Nautilus as file manager (XFCE desktop isn't active, Nautilus handles it), and I have a wxPython 2.8.8.0 application with a FileBrowseButton that works as expected, except for the "Network" shortcut on the left side of the FileDialog, that is missing.

I tried with other applications too: Firefox shows the same behaviour, GIMP *has* the "Network" shortcut, while OpenOffice 2.4 has a "mix" of the two (no "Network" but it shows Nautilus-mounted shares)

Another thing: if I install fusesmb, the "Network" shortcut *does* show within my application too.

Since fusesmb (actually, smbclient) isn't completely stable on Ubuntu Intrepid, I'd like to avoid using it, so my question is: any hint on how I could force the file picker to show the Network? Is it a Gnome-VFS problem maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825724/network-aware-wx-filedialog/876524#876524) to my other question