# Network-aware wx.FileDialog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wxpython

I'm using wx.FileDialog in a wxPython 2.8.8.0 application, under Xubuntu 8.10.. My problem is that this dialog isn't network-aware, so I can't browse Samba shares.
I see that this problem plagues other applications too (Firefox, Audacious...) so I'd like to ask where I could find informations on how to make it work.
Is that dialog supposed to be already network-aware? Am I missing something? Some library maybe? Or should I write my own implementation?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin Dunn himself told me that

> It's using the "native" GTK file
>   dialog, just like the other apps, so 
>   there isn't anything that wx can do
>   about it.

So as a workaround I ended up installing gvfs-fuse and browsing
the network through $HOME/.gvfs.. A bit klunky but it works.

Comment: It looks like there's been some activity on the GTK front: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586367 (included since GTK 2.24.18)